# Websolr issue in Rails and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am maintaining client website which built in `rails and Postgres` database and deployed on `Heroku server`.

This website used websolr for search. But suddenly from few days got issue regarding `websolr`. Got below error:

```
Error is on websolr: Error: {"code":403,"message":"Cluster is currently read-only for maintenance. Please try your request again in a few minutes. See status.websolr.com or contact support@websolr.com for updates."}
```

I tried to find out solutions but no any where mention specific this issue.

Let me know if any one have knowledge or faced before same issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open a support ticket and Heroku will escalate it to WebSolr.

Answer (score 0):

I got solutions as I discuss with Heroku server guys and send them Websolr link which used in my app.

So, issue was websolr URL. Websolr URL was in maintenance.

Thanks